# firebase serve: supervisorPort (5001) is already in use

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I built this [React App](https://github.com/YikSanChan/react-redux-todos), that allows users to add todo item, and mark an item as completed/active. Todo items are stored in cloud firestore.

I want to enable full-text search on the app, and one way is to create a cloud function that writes index to Algolia whenever cloud firestore witnesses a create operation.

Inside my app root directory, I [initialize cloud functions](https://github.com/YikSanChan/react-redux-todos/commit/e1e228140c6aed0cc20b0025e8a25130a58b2cc8) and then [implement the onTodoAdded function](https://github.com/YikSanChan/react-redux-todos/commit/afa3f7da61fd99fc7f9d3afa104ad7e7aa7cc49f). After done, I run `firebase serve` under `functions` directory and get the errors:

```
=== Serving from '/Users/evan/source/react-redux-todos'...

i  functions: Preparing to emulate functions.
Warning: You're using Node.js v10.6.0 but Google Cloud Functions only supports v6.11.5.
i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: build
✔  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000
error: SUPERVISOR error Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:5001
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1335:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1383:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1509:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:61:10)
error: supervisorPort (5001) is already in use
i  functions: No HTTPS functions found. Use firebase functions:shell if you would like to emulate other types of functions.
```

For a complete debug log, find [here](https://gist.github.com/YikSanChan/773764a6db616598a6111830ef5ea42b).

However, this command works fine: `firebase serve --only functions`.

```
=== Serving from '/Users/evan/source/react-redux-todos'...

i  functions: Preparing to emulate functions.
Warning: You're using Node.js v10.6.0 but Google Cloud Functions only supports v6.11.5.
i  functions: No HTTPS functions found. Use firebase functions:shell if you would like to emulate other types of functions.
```

Since it says supervisorPort(5001) is already in use, I `lsof -i:5001` and finds no process. I also shut down my laptop and restart, gets the same error.

I find the similar issue [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-functions-emulator/issues/173#issuecomment-407428310), however didn't find the solution.

Comment: What version of the firebase cli?  `firebase --version`

Comment: `firebase --version` => `5.0.1`

Comment: What if you upgrade to the latest 5.1.1?

Comment: I just tried, no luck, same error :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I still don't know the reason, but adding `--port=9000` solves the problem. For example, `firebase serve --only functions --port=9000`. Credits to [restPort (5001) is already in use #142](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-functions-emulator/issues/142#issuecomment-344359186).

Comment: Not working for me. It gives me another error 'Port 9001 is not open'.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same error after updating to macOS Mojave 10.14.1 (was fine with 10.14). `error: supervisorPort (5001) is already in use` and it led me down this rabbit hole of additional updates and configuration that eventually got it to work.

**1 Update Node Packages**

I updated these items to these versions (latest as of this writing)

- firebase-functions: 2.1.0
- firebase: 5.5.8

I deleted by node_modules folder and reinstalled all the packages.

**2 Firestore Emulator Setup Required**

Next time I attempted to serve, firebase gave me this error:
`Setup required, please run: firebase setup:emulators:firestore`

Because of the weird permissions issues I initially had with mac, I actually have to run
`node_modules/.bin/firebase setup:emulators:firestore`

**3 Then.... Fix Java Runtime Issues**

On my next serve attempt, I was presented with `firestore: No Java runtime present, requesting install.` Mac presents a popup leading to a page where you can "download java for mac". This isn't what you actually need. You really need the [Java SE Development Kit](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) which enables command line interface.

**Then... You may get these errors** the next time you try to serve.

```
error: restPort (5002) is already in use
error: SUPERVISOR error Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:5001
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1351:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1392:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1501:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:97:10)
error: supervisorPort (5001) is already in use
```

But Firebase still ended up continuing to successfully serve somehow, despite these errors. And it still shows my app over `http://localhost:5000`.

Hope this helps!